# How to use Macromedia Flash in Jade?

Tags: flash, pug

I want to use Macromedia Flash in my Jade template, does Jade support Flash?

Comment: I don't know, but I do know that Adobe acquired Macromedia back in 2005, and Macromedia ceased to exist over six years ago. So maybe it is time to stop calling it "Macromedia Flash", and maybe have better luck searching for info by dropping the "Macromedia" part ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure it does :-)  Jade is just an HTML pseudo language, so anything it outputs will be HTML.  All of that aside - you really should be using something like swfobject to render your flash tags:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

But the basic concept of jade is using Jade syntax instead of HTML.  So instead of something like this:

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='300' height='300' id='player1' name='player1'>
   <param name='movie' value='player.swf'>
   <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
   <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
   <param name='flashvars' value='file=playlist.xml'>
   <embed id='player1'
          name='player1'
          src='player.swf'
          width='300'
          height='300'
          allowscriptaccess='always'
          allowfullscreen='true'
          flashvars="file=playlist.xml"
   />
</object>
```

you would type something like this:

```
object(classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000', width='300', height='300', id='player1', name='player1')
   param(name='movie', value='player.swf')
   param(name='allowfullscreen', value='true')
   embed(id='player1',
          name='player1',
          src='player.swf'
          width='300',
          height='300',
          allowscriptaccess='always',
          allowfullscreen='true',
          flashvars="file=playlist.xml")
```

I hope this helps clear some things up for you.  Happy coding!